# Python highlight searchValue in textfield

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I was following [this guide](https://medium.com/@pauloxnet/full-text-search-in-django-with-postgresql-4e3584dee4ae), about django search.

```
search_value = request.query_params['searchvalue']

documents = Document.objects.filter(
    raw_text__icontains=search_value
).values_list('doc_id', flat=True)

return documents
```

This gets a list of document id's based on a search value. But in some of the document objects the raw_text textfield include the search_value more than once. But I still only get the doc_id once.

Is there a way to get the doc_id for every hit in the filter?

Comment: Can I ask what you're trying to do this for? You might be able to do something with [`SearchRank`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/postgres/search/#searchrank) to order by the amount of matches..

Comment: I tried but rank is used when you want to sort the result after the number of 'hits' the search_value appears in the documents. So it still only returns one document id even though the document has the search_value two or more times.

Comment: I dont think Django provides anything to perform this type of search. I think loops "might" be a good solution here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was not successful in solving this issue using filter. So I looked for Highlighting Results on Google and found [PostgreSQL Text Search](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/textsearch-controls.html).

This search though a textfield and returns snippets of this text. And highlight the search_values.

My final code looks like this:

```
    search_value = request.query_params['searchvalue']

    queryset = Document.objects.extra(
        select={
            'snippet': (
                "ts_headline(raw_text, plainto_tsquery(%s), "
                "'StartSel=*,StopSel=*,MaxFragments=2,"
                "FragmentDelimiter=...,MaxWords=8,MinWords=1')"
            ),
        },
        where=["search @@ plainto_tsquery(%s)"],
        params=[search_value],
        select_params=[search_value, search_value]
    )

    return Response(queryset.values('id', 'title', 'snippet', 'doc_number'))
```

I hope this will help others :)